# Laravel mix не минифицирует

Tags: javascript, laravel, webpack

Решил собрать все свои нативные скрипты во едино и столкнулся с проблемой, не минифицирует (а сейчас и вовсе выдаёт ошибки)...
Использую конструкцию:

```
mix.scripts([
    'public/js/admin.js',
    'public/js/dashboard.js'
], 'public/js/all.js');
```

Как ни странно `npm run watch` выдаёт ошибки, а `npm run watch-poll` - запускается без них. Но выходной файл так и не минифицируется...

Сам `webpack.mix.js`:

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');

mix.scripts([
   'resources/js/games/xxx.js',
   'resources/js/games/xxx.js',
          ....
   'resources/js/games/xxx.js',

], 'public/games/xxx/js/main.js');
```

Comment: полностью webpack.mix.js можете привести?

Comment: Добавил в вопрос

Comment: запуск прописан в package.json в секции scripts?

Comment: минифицировать - это npm run production